# $L_2$ is a set of all words where $w$ is an element of $A^*$ such that $w$ is a palindrome

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am not really good at generating grammars, because I find it very hard to come up with rules. However, after a lot of trial and error, this is what I could generate:

A={a,b}
Vt={a,b}
Vn={S,A,B}
R=
S->BS
S->AS
S->e
A->a
B->b

was this the correct way? if no, what could be improved? thank you!

Comment: Consider starting with $S$, then use $S -> AS$ then use $S->BS$ and then $S->e$. You would get $S \to AS \to ABS \to ABe$. Then that would give $ab$ which is not a palindrome.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have any suggestions or hints as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hint: If $w$ is a palindrome, that starts with $a$, then what does it end with and what can you say about everything between the first and last?

Comment: Oh I figured it out! I used S->e, S->a,S->b,S->aSa, S->bSb. Thank you!